# Getting "You must install .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.3 (x86)" with correct runtime installed

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-runtime

An application built targeting .NET 6 is showing the following message when double-clicking the EXE in Windows Explorer:

> To run this application, you must install .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.3
> (x86)

[image: Install .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.3 (x86)]

This runtime (6.0.3 x86) is installed on the machine though. I have confirmed this using the `dotnet --info` command:

[image: dotnet --info output]

I also tried 6.0.4 runtimes but those didn't work either.

This happens on a Windows 10 machine but I also tested this on Windows 11:

1. Downloaded the Windows 11 dev virtual machine in Hyper-V.
2. Removed .NET 6 with Visual Studio Installer.
3. Installed `windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.3-win-x86` from Microsoft's [Download .NET 6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) page.

The same happens with the (Windows 10) MSIX Packaging Tool Environment machine you can download in Hyper-V. In this .NET 6 is not installed. Same result after installing `windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.3-win-x86`.

Setting the Target CPU option (in Project Properties > Compile) to Any CPU yields a similar result, asking for the .NET Desktop Runtime x64 version which I have also installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Build process generates:

1. `assembly_name.deps`
2. `assembly_name.pdb`
3. `assembly_name.runtimeconfig.json`

I was able to launch the application by including the `runtimeconfig.json` file.

With .NET Framework applications, it was possible to simply copy the EXE and DLLs but it seems like this is not possible with .NET Core applications.

A better approach is to use the Publish feature which can properly bundle all the necessary files into a [single EXE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli) for distribution.

Comment: This works for my WinForms port! Just clarifying: the author does note that the .NET *Desktop* Runtime is needed, and also these files go to the same location as the EXE.

Comment: Ooh, are we saying copy the files from the dotnet folder into the application folder???

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque this is what I ended up doing: [Single-file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli)

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure to install ".NET Desktop Runtime" instead of ".NET Runtime" for WPF
you can get it [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) for .NET 6

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing single-file deployment for my console app.

I modified my `ProjectName.csproj` like so:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <!-- WinExe will hide the console window from appearing, so people won't close the app with X button. -->
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <!-- Prevent the app to publish files for languages other than english -->
  <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
  <!-- Publish as single file -->
  <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
  <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  <!-- To embed native binaries of the core runtime that are separate files into the single file. -->
  <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- To remove .pdb files from the release build. -->
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>None</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```